# Cannot connect to file server: "Access is Denied"

Tags: windows-10, networking, nas, mapped-drive, file-server

I have been using Ubiquiti's Unifi line of networking equipment for a few years. Our router went out and I had to put in a temporary (another brand) while I waited for a new one to come in. Since that time, all Windows 10 computers that I use (Microsoft login) can no longer connect to the server to map network drives. I always get an "Access Denied" message. However, if I connect via a Windows 7 computer, everything works fine. (Maybe all Windows 10 machines updated to a new patch at coincidentally the same time!?) I've since replaced the temporary router with a new USG and STILL have the connection issues! The username on the server is the same as the username on my Windows 10 PCs, but with a different password. I've tried deleting the saved credentials from the Windows machines, but the issue still happens.

Usually, the only way I can fix the issue is to unmap all of the network drives (10-12) and remap them! I've tried setting the server password to the same as the client login user password and it works as expected, which leads me to believe Windows 10 is having trouble storing separate passwords.

How can I solve this issue so that my network drives automatically connect as they always have in the past?

Comment: Have you tried having the same password on the server as for the clients?

Comment: Could it be that your new router assigned a different IP to your server ? Are you sure you mapped by hostname and not by ip? If nothing else helps, [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5a21ebd8-5267-492f-a576-c720090a939f/file-server-ip-changing-how-to-deal-with-drive-mapping-problem?forum=winserverfiles) moght point you to a solution of remapping via a script

Comment: Have a look at the answers in this post: [Windows 10 cannot access network shared locations or drives](https://serverfault.com/questions/888690/windows-10-cannot-access-network-shared-locations-or-drives) This post helped me fix an issue where mapped drives would'nt reconnect after restarting Windows 10 machines.

Comment: @harrymc I do not wish to set the passwords the same, but I'm sure that would work. I'll check tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: @1NN I am certain it is mapped by name as I have to redo it every boot cycle. And, I am certain the IP address has not changed as it is statically assigned.

Comment: I will check this tomorrow...

Comment: What are the results of your test?

Comment: @harrymc I changed the user password on the server to the same as the Microsoft account used to login and the drives map properly. So, it tells me there is some issue on the Windows 10 side with managing separate passwords when the username is the same, even though they are different machines.

Comment: You could try deleting Windows credentials in *Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager > Manage your credentials*, then redoing them.

Comment: @harrymc that was the very first thing I tried when the issue started happening. However, if choose to store the credentials, the issue happens again as soon as the computer is rebooted.

Comment: See my answer .

Answer (score 1):

If during the time that the replacement router was used,
the Windows 10 computers have had some error in the credentials
used, the first step should be to clean out the stored credentials.

Deleting Windows credentials is done in
*Control Panel > User Accounts > Credential Manager >
Manage your credentials*.

After the old credentials are cleaned out, you could again login
to the network shares, to see if they now work as well as before.

If this doesn't help, then this is an error in Windows 10 that
was introduced by some Microsoft update.

You could report the problem to Microsoft via the Feedback Hub,
while for the present use the same password for server and clients.
This is not an ideal situation, but it will work until a better
solution is found.

Answer (score 0):

This Microsoft document describes the issue:

[Guest access in SMB2 and SMB3 disabled by default in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/guest-access-in-smb2-is-disabled-by-default)

If you want to enable insecure guest access, you can configure the following Group Policy settings:

Open the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
In the console tree, select Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Lanman Workstation.
For the setting, right-click Enable insecure guest logons and select Edit.
Select Enabled and select OK.

To set the value without using group policy, set the following following DWORD registry value to 1 (insecure guest auth enabled) or 0 (insecure guest auth disabled):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation\Parameters
AllowInsecureGuestAuth

This helped me fix an issue where mapped drives would'nt reconnect after restarting Windows 10 machines.

Comment: I will check this tomorrow...

Comment: This outlines Active Directory and Group Policy procedures, neither of which I am using. This is a simple folder share from a Unix-based file server.

Comment: re: AD and Group policy, This is simply a setting for the windows client lan manager. Windows 10 purposely "broke" (deprecated) SMB v.1 support because of ransomware vulnerability. The fact that Windows 7 still works with the shares points to this possibility. You can enable SMB v.1 manually if you wish. Note that the SMB support change is *not* a new update, so this still may not apply if your machines were relatively up to date with security patches.

Comment: @Yorik we got a new Windows 10 PC a couple of years ago and had to enable SMB1 support on setup as it would not even attempt to connect to the server and gave an SMB1 error. However, that error is not being given and I can still connect to the server from all Windows 10 PCs; I just have to disconnect all mapped drives and reconnect them all. I believe it has to do with how the password is being stored (or not stored). However, I will enable these policies and check anyway.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can check by disabling win 10 Firewall as the it has more new features
   than the Windows 7 Firewall
2. If it is a windows server you could install the file server role & share
   the folder from the server end by giving everyone access within the on-prem
   environment.(CAn control the permission via NTFS permission)
3. Please let us know whether your computer is connected to the domain or just
   a stand alone user PC & a server
4. Finally as a workaround create a logon script policy to map drive during
   every logon & create is as a .bat file & schedule it in windows task
   scheduler to run at the startup

net use [driveletter]: /delete

net use [driveletter]: \server\share /user:[username] password /persistent:yes

For more info fallow ms articles about how to map/delete drive via CMD

Comment: This is a UNIX-based server with simple folder sharing. The connection is a simple username/password connection.